# What is omega supression for a lock-in amplifier?

Tags: psd

I'm using a lock-in amplifier for PSD measurements.  The lock-in amplifier has an option for omega supression (in dB.) I'm unable to find resources on the lock-in amplifier's manual or online about what exactly this means.

Comment: Lullapalanza - What is the brand and model of the amplifier? Any web links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, omega supression refers to supressing the lock-in frequency from the output when using the [three omega method for measuring thermal conductivity.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468469/clarification-on-the-three-omega-method-for-measuring-thermal-conductivity)

You use a particular frequency (omega) to do the test.  The interesting changes happen at three times the original frequency (3 omega.)  The lock-in amplifier needs to be able to pick up **only** the harmonic (3 omega) while ignoring the original frequency (omega.) This ability is rated as "omega suppression."

The three omega method apparently consists of sweeps of the original frequency (omega) while evaluating the 3 harmonic (3 omega.)

Some lock-in amplifiers have the ability to turn the omega supression on or off, or to select different levels of suppression.  Better suppression of the original signal (omega) comes at the cost of slower sweep times.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and editing the original question.

Comment: @Lullapalanza -   What  JRE said (I think). Plus there may also be options for 2 - Omega suppression = second harmonic. In many applications the fundamental frequency is of interest so omega-suppression would not be of value.